# Qt queued exit event for worker object in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

`MyClass` object has a worker `QObject`, that is working in another thread:

```
class MyClass {
....
private:
   QThread thread;
   Worker worker; // inherits QObject
};

...

worker.moveToThread(&thread);
```

Now when I call `thread.exit()` my worker thread stops instantly. I would prefer it to finish all pending events, then quit.

I have tried something like "queued exit":

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(signalFinish()),
        &thread, SLOT(quit()),Qt::QueuedConnection);

 ...

void MyClass::finish()
{
    emit signalFinish();
    worker.disconnect(); // do not queue any more events
    thread.wait();
}
```

but it doesn't work. It will wait forever...

How to I stop `QThread` after it's event loop will process all pending events?

Comment: maybe have a `QuitThread` slot in your worker (which will quit the current thread `QThread::currentThread()->quit();`), and connect to it instead of the `thread`'s `quit` slot. that way the `QuitThread` slot will get executed after all previously queued slots are executed. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread and `MyClass` instances both live in the same thread - likely the main thread:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
  ...
  Q_ASSERT(this->thread() == thread.thread());
```

Yet the events you're queuing to the worker object go to the worker thread:

```
  worker.moveToThread(&thread);
  Q_ASSERT(worker.thread() == &thread);
  Q_ASSERT(worker.thread() != thread.thread());
```

The queued connection is precisely the wrong thing to do because as soon as you wait on the worker thread, the main thread's event loop won't run and won't issue any more events to the thread. The `quit` call will never be delivered, since it's delivered in the main thread, but the main thread is blocked.

Instead, take the advantage of `quit` being a thread-safe method. Call it from the worker thread itself:

```
//                                    vvvvvvv thread context object for the call
connect(this, &MyClass::signalFinish, &worker, [this]{ thread.quit(); });
// the `quit()` will execute in `worker.thread()`
```

Note that the thread context object is an object whose `thread()` the call will be executed in. It should **not** be a `QThread` instance, in most cases!

When the `signalFinish` is emitted, a `QMetaCallEvent` carrying the functor above will be queued in the worker thread's queue, and will get executed after any existing call (and other) events are processed first.

Since you're calling `finish` in the main thread, you probably don't want to wait on the thread since that will block the GUI and make your application unresponsive.

As it seems you're submitting job items to a worker thread, you might be better served by `QtConcurrent::run` that submits job items to a thread pool, and does all the thread management for you. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38003211/1329652) for a complete example. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38023574/1329652) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38109800/1329652) for some related tidbits.

Comment: thank you! calling QThread::currentThread()->quit() from the worker solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

See [this relevant StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613830/2116716)

> You can use [QThread::exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613830/2116716) call to run your thread in the event loop. The thread will run it until you tell your thread to exit by calling [QThread::exit()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qthread.html#exit). So some sample code can look like this:

```
void DownloadWorker::run()
 {
    DownloadManager* pDownloadManager = new DownloadManager(this);
    connect(pDownloadManager, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(exit()));
    connect(pDownloadManager, SIGNAL(error()), SLOT(exit()));
    pDownloadManager->download();
    exec();
 }
```

> That would guarantee you that your thread won't quit until the "finished()" signal of your DownloadManager is issued.
>
> Note: Here I put an example of how to solve your problem but I don't know your whole app code. That means there is not guarantee this code is thread safe and consistent. You need to take care of the mutexes and all the correct synchronization yourself. Be very careful ! Working with such a "low level" thread API requites good understanding of multithereading.